# Filepicker.io rails app with multiple files

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, filepicker.io

I can't find any examples or documentation for how to handle multiple file uploads with my rails 3.2 application and filepicker.io. Can anyone assist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was just recently added, see https://github.com/Filepicker/filepicker-rails/pull/35

Comment: I can not figure out how to add it. It does not work when I do this:

<%= f.filepicker_field :filepicker_url, :multiple => "true" %>

I apologize if this is a dumb question. Also, I am not sure how it would add multipe instances of the model to the database for each image that was being uploaded.

Comment: Ok so I figured it out, When the file_url is uploaded its as a hash of files.. so you just need to .split(",") them into a hash and you can display them on a page. Thanks for your help!